# onEdit function not showing user name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a simple script:

```
function onEdit(e){
var name = Session.getActiveUser();
var range = e.range;
range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date()+"By:"+" "+name);
}
```

The results are like this:

```
Last modified: Wed Dec 17 2014 15:50:24 GMT-0500 (EST)By:
```

But there is just a blank where the User's name should be... thoughts?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your script. It works perfectly.

Comment: please also read these 2 documentations [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script needs authorization to be able to execute `Session.getActiveUser()`. Your code above  works for me if I first run the script in the editor and authorize it, then the note with the user info is added to the cells on edit.

Comment: I was not running it and therefore authorizing.  Thanks!